# I want to improve my latex code for this table. It's for my thesis. Any sugestion?

Tags: tables, overleaf

Thanks in advance. I'd like to improve the appearance of my table. Maybe it could be flipped horizontally. I prefer tables without many lines.

```
\documentclass[         % Clase del documento
    12pt,               % Tamaño de letra
    letterpaper,        % Tamaño de papel
    oneside,            % Impresión a ujncara
    final               % Versión final
]{book}
 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%tablas
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}   % Paquetes para tablas
\usepackage{longtable}
%--- Márgenes del documento
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,inner=2.5cm,outer=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[skip=.3\baselineskip plus 2pt,indent]{parskip} % Salto entre párrafos 
% skip= .5\baselineskip plus 2pt -> Valor por defecto
% 

\title{tabla larga}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{table}[htbp!]

\centering
\caption{Artículos científicos de oxihaluros de bismuto sintetizados por ruta hidro/solvotermal.}
\begin{tabular}{|p{4.5cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{1cm}|}
    \hline
    \centering Material & \centering Condiciones  & \centering Morfología & \centering Contaminante &  Ref\\
    \hline\hline
    Bi$_4$O$_5$Cl$_2$, Bi$_{24}$O$_{31}$Cl$_{10}$, Bi$_3$O$_4$Cl, Bi$_{
    12}$O$_{17}$Cl$_2$ &    Hidrotermal; 350 - 550 °C & Nanohojas, Nanofibras & \centering -    &1\\
    \hline
    BiOI, Bi$_4$O$_5$I$_2$, Bi$_7$O$_9$I$_3$ &  Solvotermal; 12 h; 130 °C & Microesferas jerárquicas & RhB, Fenol & 2   \\
    \hline
    Bi$_4$O$_5$I$_2$ & Solvotermal; pH=9; 12 h; 150 °C & Microesferas jerárquicas & 4-tert-butilfenol & 3\\
    \hline
   BiOBr, Bi$_4$O$_5$Br$_2$, Bi$_{12}$O$_{17}$Br$_2$, Bi$_5$O$_7$Br, Bi$_3$O$_4$Br, Bi$_{24}$O$_{31}$Br &   Hidrotermal; 12, 24, 36 h ; 60-280°C ; pH=1-14 &    Partículas irregulares, Nanohojas, Rodillos irregulares  & Violeta cristal &    4\\
    \hline
   BiO(ClBr)$_{(1-x)/2}$I$_x$ & Solvotermal; 12 h; 160 °C & Estructuras jerárquicas de tipo flor & 2-propanol & 5\\
    \hline
    Bi$_4$O$_5$Br$_2$ & Hidrotermal; pH = 11; 24 h; 140 °C & Nanohojas ultradelgadas &  Ciprofluoxacina & 6
\\
    \hline
    Bi$_4$O$_5$I$_2$, Bi$_5$O$_7$I &    Solvotermal; 17 h; 160 °C
Calcinación & Nanohojas ultradelgadas & CO$_2$ &    7
\\
    \hline
    Bi$_4$O$_5$X$_2$ (X = Br, I)    &Solvotermal, 16 h a 160 °C &Nanohojas  &Evolución de H$_2$ &8
\\
    \hline
   Bi$_4$O$_5$I$_2$ &   Solvotermal / Microhondas; 20 min; 120 °C & Microesferas &  Fenol & 9\\
    \hline
    Bi$_4$O$_5$Br$_x$I$_{2-x}$ &    Solvotermal; 16 h; 160 °C & Microesferas jerárgicas &   Conversión de CO$_2$ y reducción de Cr(VI)  & 10
\\
    \hline
   Bi$_4$O$_5$I$_2$ &   Solvotermal; pH=9; 12 h; 140 °C & Nano hojuelas & BPA, Fenol, Metilparaben, Propilparaben & 11
\\
    \hline
   Bi$_4$O$_5$Br$_2$ &  Hidrotermal; 24 h; 140 °C; pH=11.5   & Nanohojas &  BPA & 12
\\
    \hline
  BiOBr, Bi$_4$O$_5$Br$_2$ & Solvotermal; 16 h; 160 °C &    Microesferas    & Conversión de CO$_2$  & 13
\\
    \hline
  Bi$_4$O$_5$I$_2$  & Solvotermal; pH=12; 24 h; 140 °C &    Nanohojas & Rh B, CIP    & 14
\\
    \hline
  Bi$_4$O$_5$Br$_2$, Bi$_{12}$O$_{17}$Br$_2$ & Hidrotermal; 24 h; 150 °C    & Nanohojas &   Oxidación de NO &   15
\\
    \hline

\end{tabular}
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace{300pt} Continúa en la siguiente página.

\end{tabbing}
\label{t2}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example, instead of a code snippet.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Do you want a more efficient code that basically produces the se putpu or, do you want a better looking output. I ff it's the latter you're interested in, please add a sketch/description of the expected output, as better looking if often quite subjective.

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to complete small document with your table. Page layout has strong influence on table appearing.

Comment: Title of your question is misleading, consequently people close it as opinion based. But you have other serious problems: **(i)** your table is actually long table, which automatically break table over multiple  pages **(ii)**  `longtable` define table headers and footers, so you not need to use `tabbing` for indicate continuation of table on the next page, **(iii)** use of `\ce{...}˙˙ is cumbersome, etc. I suggest you to edit your question, change question title, add explanation what you like to change in your table and in the first place provide MWE (a small but complete document ).

Comment: @Zarko: what exactly speaks against the use of \ce for chemical formulae?

Comment: In order to rotate the table to a landscape orientation, take a look at the pdflscape package. To make sure, the table spans multiple pages without manually splitting the table, take a look at the xltabular package. With the help of this package, you can at the same time ensure that, your table does not exceed the available linewidth. Regarding the lines: remove all hline commands and | from your code and use the commands from the booktabs package instead.

Comment: @leandriis, in OP cases I suggest to use `\ce`, however, in table are not used consistently. Special, where they are writes as mix with math (for example `BiO(ClBr)$_{(1-x)/2}$I$_x$ `) and as array  `\ce{Bi4O5Cl2, Bi24O31Cl10, Bi3O4Cl}` (which cannot be broken in two lines instead `\ce{Bi4O5Cl2}, \ce{Bi24O31Cl10}, \ce{Bi3O4Cl}`, etc. Since OP is novice here, I like to encourage him to edit and reformulated his question and with this ask people to reopen it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a combination of `xltabular`, `pdflscape`, `booktabs`, `mhchem` and `siunitx`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[         % Clase del documento
    12pt,               % Tamaño de letra
    letterpaper,        % Tamaño de papel
    oneside,            % Impresión a ujncara
    final               % Versión final
]{book}
 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%tablas
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}   % Paquetes para tablas
\usepackage{xltabular}
%--- Márgenes del documento
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,inner=2.5cm,outer=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[skip=.3\baselineskip plus 2pt,indent]{parskip} % Salto entre párrafos 
% skip= .5\baselineskip plus 2pt -> Valor por defecto
% 

\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\setlength{\LTcapwidth}{\linewidth}
\sisetup{list-units = single, list-final-separator={\text{,} }, range-phrase=--}
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{L{4.25cm} *{3}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X} c}
  \caption{Artículos científicos de oxihaluros de bismuto sintetizados por ruta hidro/solvotermal.}\\
  \toprule
   Material &  Condiciones  &  Morfología &  Contaminante &  Ref\\
  \midrule
\endfirsthead
  \caption{Continuación - Artículos científicos de oxihaluros de bismuto sintetizados por ruta hidro/solvotermal.}\\
  \toprule
   Material &  Condiciones  &  Morfología &  Contaminante &  Ref\\
  \midrule
\endhead
  \bottomrule
  \multicolumn{5}{r@{}}{Continúa en la siguiente página.}\\
\endfoot
  \bottomrule
\endlastfoot
    \ce{Bi4O5Cl2}, \ce{Bi24O31Cl10}, \ce{Bi3O4Cl}, \ce{Bi12O17Cl2} 
      &  Hidrotermal; \qtyrange{350}{550}{\celsius}
        & Nanohojas, Nanofibras 
          &   
            &1\\
    \addlinespace
    \ce{BiOI}, \ce{Bi4O5I2}, \ce{Bi7O9I3} 
      &   Solvotermal; \qty{12}{\hour}; \qty{130}{\celsius} 
        & Microesferas jerárquicas 
          & RhB, Fenol 
            & 2  \\
    \addlinespace
    \ce{Bi4O5I2} 
      & Solvotermal; pH=9; \qty{12}{\hour}; \qty{150}{\celsius} 
        & Microesferas jerárquicas 
          & 4-tert-butilfenol 
            & 3\\
    \addlinespace
   \ce{BiOBr}, \ce{Bi4O5Br2}, \ce{Bi12O17Br2}, \ce{Bi5O7Br}, \ce{Bi3O4Br}, \ce{Bi24O31Br} 
     &    Hidrotermal; \qtylist{12; 24; 36}{\hour}; \qtyrange{60}{280}{\celsius}; pH=\numrange{1}{14} 
       &    Partículas irregulares, Nanohojas, Rodillos irregulares  
         & Violeta cristal 
           &    4\\
   \addlinespace
   \ce{BiO(ClBr)_{(1-x)/2}I_{x}} 
     & Solvotermal; \qty{12}{\hour}; \qty{160}{\celsius} 
       & Estructuras jerárquicas de tipo flor 
         & 2-propanol 
           & 5\\
    \addlinespace
    \ce{Bi4O5Br2} 
      & Hidrotermal; pH=11; \qty{24}{\hour}; \qty{140}{\celsius} 
        & Nanohojas ultradelgadas 
          &  Ciprofluoxacina 
            & 6 \\
    \addlinespace
    \ce{Bi4O5I2}, \ce{Bi5O7}I 
      &    Solvotermal;  \qty{17}{\hour}; \qty{160}{\celsius} Calcinación 
        & Nanohojas ultradelgadas 
          & \ce{CO2} 
            &    7\\
    \addlinespace
    \ce{Bi4OX5} (X = Br, I)    
      & Solvotermal;  \qty{16}{\hour} a \qty{160}{\celsius} 
        & Nanohojas  
          & Evolución de \ce{H2} 
            &8\\
    \addlinespace
    \ce{Bi4O5I2} 
      &   Solvotermal / Microhondas;  \qty{20}{\min}; \qty{120}{\celsius} 
        & Microesferas 
          &  Fenol 
            & 9\\
    \addlinespace
    \ce{Bi4O5Br_{x}I_{2-x}} 
      &    Solvotermal;  \qty{16}{\hour}; \qty{160}{\celsius} 
        & Microesferas jerárgicas 
          &   Conversión de \ce{CO2} y reducción de \ce{Cr^{VI}}  
            & 10 \\
    \end{xltabular}
\end{landscape}



\end{document}
```